# How to read response after an echo command on /dev/ttyACM0 device file?

Tags: arduino, linux-kernel, serial-port

I am using a USB-RLY08-B relay device ([datasheet](https://static.rapidonline.com/pdf/60-5058.pdf)). I am able to set the relay switches on/off using the following commands :

```
echo -n -e '\x74' > /dev/ttyACM0
```

However to get the relay states, i need to pass Hex 5B code to the relay. The problem is I am not able to figure out how to read the response back after the echo command.

I tried

```
read X < /dev/ttyACM0
```

but it hangs.

Comment: We have been using such in the laboratory. I can share the parts of the script we are using (here is the core of it): `local data=$(/usr/bin/printf '\x5b' | /bin/nc -w1 $tcp_addr $tcp_port); local state=$(($(printf '%d' "'$data") >> $((port - 1)) & 1))`

Comment: @0andriy Thanks. One hint I got that I could use a pipeline. So I tried `echo -n -e '\x5B' > /dev/ttyACM0 | read -n 1 result` . It didn't hang this time, but unfortunately `echo $result` turns out to be  empty. I need to think more. Thanks for the help. Never thought such a simple thing can be that tricky ;)

Comment: Shell is very complex and hard to learn programming language. So, no surprises here. By the way, I have noticed, that you are using */dev/ttyACM0* directly. We, for sake of unification, use `ser2net` for such devices (we have also Ethernet ones).

Answer (score 0):

`read` waits for a whole line to be read from the file or device:

From [the MAN page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html):

> read - Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.

Because your device only returns a single byte, `read` hangs waiting for a newline.

If you use `-n` or `-N`:

```
read -n 1 X < /dev/ttyACM0
```

Then `read` will read the first byte and then quit.

The behaviour of `-n` and `-N` are slightly different but this may not be relevant for your application:

```
  -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
        for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS
        characters are read before the delimiter
  -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
        EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
```

Comment: Yes I read about this `-n ` already here : https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/269232-read-line-serial-device-bash.html but still it hangs for me once I do `echo -n -e '\x5B' > /dev/ttyACM0` and then try to read back using `read -n 1 X < /dev/ttyACM0`.